# Athena for Spark cell char limitations

Tags: amazon-athena

When I exceed the number 50987 chars in a cell I encounter the following error which is strictly connected with the number of characters in Athena's notebook cell:

> Exception encountered while running calculation: An error occurred
> (InternalServerException) when calling the StartCalculationExecution
> operation (reached max retries: 3): An internal server error occurred

I tried to find information in Athena's documentation but the only thing I found about char limitation is:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/notebooks-spark-troubleshooting-code-block-size-limit.html

But AWS is stating there:

> Athena for Spark has a known calculation code block size limit of
> 68000 characters

Which in terms of number differs. My number is 50987 < 68000 their number.

Plus the error coming from such an error (based on the doc) should look like that:

> '...' at 'codeBlock' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have
> length less than or equal to 68000

Mine error differs.

Can anyone try to explain to me:

1. Is it well well-known character limitation that I experienced that they didn't mention in the doc or could be something else?
2. Maybe - because it seems there's a different error (seems like due to timeout) - is there some possibility to change the default time / or number of retries to avoid a crash?
3. Does that mean that the char limit decreased from 68000 to 50987 and the documentation is not valid in the case of the 68000 limit?